# Number calculations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

```
let price: number = 0.7; // $
let discountPrice: number = 0.6; // $

let netPrice: number = price - discountPrice;

console.log(netPrice); // 0.09999999999999998 but not 1 cent
```

Due to IEEE 754 standard, we are losing data precision after computation.

How client side calculations are done in ecommerce applications? to maintain precision

Comment: `How client side calculations are done in ecommerce applications?` Rounding.

Comment: @meagar Do we need to always use`somePrice.toFixed(1)`? that relate to currency

Comment: Only when you display the numbers to a user.

Comment: @meagar But anyways am losing the value precision in the data, due to problems in representation

Comment: When calculating in currency, you should do the math in pennies/cents and then times by 100. Otherwise, you will run into rounding issues like this.

Comment: @overexchange You're talking about client-side calculations in JavaScript, so my assumption here is that you are displaying something like a shopping cart and your problem is that you need to render dollar values rounded to two decimal places. The accuracy of your calculations doesn't matter here, you cannot actually *use* these values for anything important, they're purely for display purposes, so using floats and `toFixed` is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For e-commerce applications and financial calculations, you should scale up your decimal values by a consistent multiplier and represent all monetary values as integers. This is to avoid the [nuances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) with floating-point math. In JavaScript we only have the floating-point data type for numeric values, but luckily **integer math under the floating-point data-type is exact**. Therefore converting monetary values to integers (e.g., `2550` cents instead of `25.50` dollars) resolves the issue.

Comment: This is how you overcome IEEE 754 representation

Comment: Can you bold this: *integer arithmetic in floating-point is exact*?

Comment: Can you generalise your answer for any currency? By saying lowest unit of money. I think, 100 is not standard for all currencies

Comment: You are correct @overexchange.  I believe this solution has multi-currency implications: "This has a notable problem – not all currencies in the world are actually decimal (Mauritiana). Also, there are currencies in the world where there are no subunits (Japanese Yen) or non-100 subunits (Jordanian Dinars), or more than one subunit (Chinese Renminbi). Eventually, you’d just recreate the floating point – probably poorly too." - https://modernweb.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-points/

Comment: @overexchange Good point, I'll modify my answer to take into account other currencies.

Comment: In terms of contract, do we transmit integers to backend?

Comment: @overexchange In what format you transmit the numbers to the backend depends on a lot of things -- including whether or not the backend language supports a decimal data type. That's probably an answer for a different StackOverflow question though.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing like this in my project. You can just use `.toFixed()`

```js
let price = 0.7; // $
let discountPrice = 0.6; // $

let netPrice = (price - discountPrice).toFixed(1);

console.log(netPrice); // correct answer
```

Also check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056569/631803

`Math.round()` will not work correctly, so go with `.toFixed()`.

Comment: If it is currency, yes, `toFixed(1)` should suffice for dollar specific currency

Comment: @overexchange Yes you got it.

Comment: @overexchange how you will represent  `1 cent`? Price should always be in currency not number.

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string which is fine for display, but for intermediary calculations, you may need to convert it back to a number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

#### 1. use toPrecision() function to truncate the float number

If you don't want big changes to your code, you can try this function:

```
function truncate(number) {
    return (parseFloat(number).toPrecision(2));
}
```

#### 2. always use the smallest unit of the money for ecommerce calculation

E.g. 0.7 dollar = 70 cents, 0.6 dollar = 60 cents

So, 0.7 dollar - 0.6 dollar = 70 cents - 60 cents = 10 cents. // will give you precise value